# Change group permission for usb device permanently

Tags: usb, permissions, groups

I want to access a USB device `ttyUSB0` from apache.
So I set:

> chgrp www-data /dev/ttyUSB0

The problem is, that every time I replug the device, I have to set to do `chgrp` again. How can I do this?

Comment: usually, /dev/ttyUSBx has group `dialout` attached, so you might add user `ẁww_data`to group `dialout`: `sudo adduser www_data dialout`

Comment: @ridgy sorry, did not solve it. After replugging the USB device, www-data still couldn't access it

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution would be to add a rule to `etc/udev/rules.d` you will find tons of tutorial on how to do it. Use **lsusb** or **dmesg** to discover pid and id of your usb than create the file/rule with your text editor and with sudo mv move it in that folder

Comment: Ok i understood (and i discovered how to do it on my own) ! Thanks for correcting my spelling mistake in the directory

Comment: Always glad to help. You might wish to expand your answer with some detail and site one of the tutorials you mention as a source. Better answers receive upvotes that will boost [your reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) here.